# Graphics3D can not show complete spheres with scaled radius

Tags: graphics3d

```
g=Graphics3D[{
  {Red, Sphere[{1, 1, 0}, Scaled[0.05`]]},
  {Green, Sphere[{1, 2, 3}, Scaled[0.05`]]},
  {Blue, Sphere[{-2, -2, 2}, Scaled[0.05`]]}}]
```

gives

[image]

Notice that spheres are all cut at the edge.

`PlotRange->All` does not work here. A more weird thing is that `AbsoluteOptions@g`

```
{AlignmentPoint -> Center, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 AutomaticImageSize -> False, Axes -> True, AxesEdge -> Automatic, 
 AxesLabel -> None, AxesOrigin -> Automatic, AxesStyle -> {}, 
 Background -> None, BaselinePosition -> Automatic, BaseStyle -> {}, 
 Boxed -> True, BoxRatios -> {1., 1., 1.}, BoxStyle -> {}, 
 ClipPlanes -> None, ClipPlanesStyle -> Automatic, 
 ColorOutput -> Automatic, ContentSelectable -> Automatic, 
 ControllerLinking -> False, ControllerMethod -> Automatic, 
 ControllerPath -> Automatic, CoordinatesToolOptions -> Automatic, 
 DisplayFunction -> Identity, Epilog -> {}, FaceGrids -> None, 
 FaceGridsStyle -> {}, FormatType -> TraditionalForm, 
 ImageMargins -> 0., ImagePadding -> All, ImageSize -> Automatic, 
 ImageSizeRaw -> Automatic, LabelStyle -> {}, Lighting -> Automatic, 
 Method -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> None, 
 PlotRange -> {{0., 1.}, {0., 1.}, {0., 1.}}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Automatic, PlotRegion -> Automatic, 
 PreserveImageOptions -> Automatic, Prolog -> {}, 
 RotationAction -> "Fit", SphericalRegion -> Automatic, 
 Ticks -> Automatic, TicksStyle -> {}, TouchscreenAutoZoom -> False, 
 ViewAngle -> Automatic, ViewCenter -> {0.5, 0.5, 0.5}, 
 ViewMatrix -> Automatic, ViewPoint -> {1.3, -2.4, 2.}, 
 ViewProjection -> Automatic, ViewRange -> All, 
 ViewVector -> Automatic, ViewVertical -> {0., 0., 1.}}
```

Notice the `PlotRange -> {{0., 1.}, {0., 1.}, {0., 1.}}`, How could that be? This is not the correct `PlotRange`, then what `PlotRange` does Mathematica actually use internally? Why can not `AbsoluteOption` correctly show it?

I know I can use for example `PlotRangePadding -> 1` to make all sphere complete. But How to make the plot range just enough for any cases without manual adjustment? I think the key is to get the correct absolute PlotRange.

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[boundingBoxDiagonal, fromScaledRadii]

boundingBoxDiagonal = EuclideanDistance @@ Transpose@
     CoordinateBounds @ Transpose[Cases[#, Sphere[c_, _] :> c, All]] &;

fromScaledRadii = ReplaceAll[#,
   Sphere[c_, Scaled @ r_] :> Sphere[c, r boundingBoxDiagonal @ #]] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
g1 = Graphics3D[{{Red, Sphere[{1, 1, 0}, Scaled[0.05]]},
       {Green, Sphere[{1, 2, 3}, Scaled[0.05]]}, 
       {Blue,  Sphere[{-2, -2, 2}, Scaled[0.05]]}}, 
      ImageSize -> Medium];

Row[{g1, Show[fromScaledRadii @ g1, PlotRangePadding -> None]}]
```

[image]

```
g2 = Graphics3D[{{Red, Sphere[{1, 1, 0}, Scaled[0.1]]}, 
       {Green, Sphere[{1, 2, 3}, Scaled[0.025]]}, 
       {Blue,  Sphere[{-2, -2, 2}, Scaled[0.2]]}}, 
      ImageSize -> Medium];

Row[{g2, Show[fromScaledRadii @ g2, PlotRangePadding -> None]}]
```

[image]

Comment: kglr, Thank you so much for answering. If I understand correctly, you convert scaled radius to absolute radius. But I think that may not be a general fix. For example, I actually need to put scaled fontsize label on each sphere, and if the sphere radius becomes absolute, the total graphics3D would be a mass when scaling.

Comment: and your boundingBoxDiagonal seems not right. If we use `Axes->True`. We can see the diagonal is approximately sqrt(43)

Comment: A sphere with scaled text would be something like `Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[{1, 1, 0}, Scaled[0.05]], 
  FontSize -> Scaled[0.05], Text[Style["A", White, Bold], {1, 1, 0}]}]`